# Having a crisp edge at the top of a box shadow via CSS?

Tags: css

I'm using the following css technique to design a box shadow around a div element...

```
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #303030;
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #303030;
box-shadow:0 0 10px #303030;
```

But is there a way to tell the css to stop the shadow effect at the top of the div?  I just want to the left, right and bottom of the div element to have the effect.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uXGKp/)

```
div{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 10px #303030;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 5px 10px #303030;
    box-shadow:0 5px 10px #303030;
}
```

Comment: I would increase to `10px` where `5px` is. +1

Answer (score 1):

To entirely get rid of the top shadow *without lengthening the bottom shadow*, my solution would be to include another element inside the div with a white background and absolutely position it to hide the top shadow.

```
<div>
    <span></span>    
</div>


div {
    margin-top:20px;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #303030;
    position:relative;
}
span {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;
    height:10px;
    width:100%;
    background:#fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QE8Bh/1/

Comment: daamsie, i really like your creativity and that would be a good solution for a flat background, but I am using rounded corners and a transparent border effect around the entire element block.  I will bookmark your solution regardless though.  thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that would add to the complexity. You'd need to add the rounded corners to the top of the span instead if you wanted to use this option. Dropping the bottom shadow is certainly the neater way to do this, but the effect is slightly different, since the shadow becomes more pronounced at the bottom than it is on the sides.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow), the second value is the vertical inset. Just update that value in order to have a "drop shadow" effect:

```
box-shadow: 0 10px 10px #303030;
```

Also, [check this article](https://catalin.red/how-to-create-slick-effects-with-css3-box-shadow/) for some other cool effects you can achieve with box-shadow.